# Boto 3 vs. Boto 2 for Amazon market place

Tags: boto3, mws

Background:
I have been using Python 2.7.13 with Boto 2.48.0 to get information from the Amazon API about my Amazon store inventory and orders, for the past year.

Issue:
When using the Boto 2.48 documentation page (http://boto.cloudhackers.com/en/latest/ref/mws.html) The message upgrade to Boto version 3 appears.  When I check the documentation on boto3 (https://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)
I see a lot of functionality for AWS, but only see a few commands for the Amazon market place, and it does not include the commands I usually use.

An example something I currently do in Boto2, and would would need to do in Boto3, is using mws.get_matching_product_for_id() to find the Model and ASIN  of a specific UPC.

Question:
Has MWS support been deprecated in version 3? Does it have a new name? Is there some other new way to access this information in Boto3?

Thank you

Comment: IMHO, MWS are not suppose to be part of AWS API, the reason of boto contains some MWS access is probably due to early day design ambiguity.  If you need comprehensive MWS, you should use its own API. i.e. :  https://developer.amazonservices.com/

Comment: Hi Mootmoot, Thank you for the response, The reason I chose Boto2 and not my own API was  the SignatureMethod I wrote for MWS was having trouble calculating properly. I was hoping Boto3 had more features, but if it has no support for MWS, I will have to stick with Boto2.If there are other wrappers, please let me know. Thank you.

Comment: You can hunt around "python mws api"  Or check this out. 
https://github.com/python-amazon-mws/python-amazon-mws

Comment: Hi mootmoot, I had looked at it over a year ago. I see that it has many updates in the last year so I will look at it again.Thank you.